# Change from display none to display inline-block and rotate at the same time with css

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, transform

How can I change from `display: none` to `display: inline-block` and rotate at the same time with css?

Here is what I am trying to do

html

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="squareV">

  </div>
  <div class="squareH">

  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.squareV {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #343434;
}

.wrapper:hover .squareV {
  display: none;
}

.squareH {
  display: none;

  transition: transform 5s;
}

.wrapper:hover .squareH {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #12dd12;

  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oobarbazanoo/76uedo40/799/)

I am expecting my code to work, but it does not work. Why?

Please, do not suggest an alternative of using one div and just changing its color on hover. I need exactly the case I explained above.

Comment: On hovering it needs to rotate and meanwhile display needs to get inline block right ?

Comment: @J.Shabu, yes, you are right. Thank you.

Comment: How about giving opacity and display inline-block at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@YaroslavTrofimov Not using `display: none;` is part of the key to this working. When using `display: none` the element is being removed from the DOM and no longer exists, and is therefore unable to be transitioned to/from. You need to use a combination of **both** `opacity` and `visibility`. `opacity: 0;` obviously makes it invisible, but using it alone it will still exist and take up space. Using it with `visibility: hidden;` stops it from taking up space and blocking other elements (it is still within the DOM though and so can be transitioned). See my example below and a link to a CodePen.

```
// html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="squareV">

  </div>
  <div class="squareH">

  </div>
</div>


// css
.wrapper {
  background: dodgerblue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.wrapper:hover .squareV {
  display: none;
}
.wrapper:hover .squareH {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
  transition: transform 1s ease;
}
.squareV {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #343434;
}
.squareH {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #12dd12;
}
```

https://codepen.io/RuNpiXelruN/pen/KGeWMV

If you need the animation to be reversed on hover out feel free to reach out. It will take some additional tweaking but i'm happy to help.

Comment: The visibility CSS property can show or hide an element without affecting the layout of a document (i.e., space is created for elements regardless of whether they are visible or not). MDN

Comment: As I've clearly explained above, visibility AND opacity need to be used. Not just one or the other.

Comment: Sorry i probably misunderstood this sentence "Using it with visibility: hidden; stops it from taking up space and blocking other elements"

Comment: I don't see why both visibility and opacity need to be used? Using only one is enough, both behave almost the same and the elemen will always take space in the DOM

Answer (score 0):

The `display:none` is preventing the transition of rotation to work. You can use an animation instead:

```css
.squareV{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #343434;
}

.wrapper:hover .squareV {
  display:none;
}

.squareH {
  display: none;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #12dd12;
}

.wrapper:hover .squareH {
  display: inline-block;
  animation:change 5s linear forwards;
}
@keyframes change{
  to {transform: rotate(-180deg);}
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="squareV">

  </div>
  <div class="squareH">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to toggle display, not visibility.

Comment: @YaroslavTrofimov you can consider an animation in this case, check the update